# Optimal method for inserting missing dates into a partitioned Snowflake table?

Tags: sql, date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-insert, partitioning

The data is currently in the following format:

| account_id | sale_month | revenue_new | revenue_expansion | revenue_churn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000001 | 2022-01-01 | 100 | 0 | 0 |
| 000001 | 2022-03-01 | 0 | 200 | 0 |
| 000001 | 2022-06-01 | 0 | 0 | -300 |

I would like the data to be in the following format:

| account_id | sale_month | revenue_opening | revenue_new | revenue_expansion | revenue_churn | revenue_closing |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000001 | 2022-01-01 | 0 | 100 | 0 | 0 | 100 |
| 000001 | 2022-02-01 | 100 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 100 |
| 000001 | 2022-03-01 | 100 | 0 | 200 | 0 | 300 |
| 000001 | 2022-04-01 | 300 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 300 |
| 000001 | 2022-05-01 | 300 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 300 |
| 000001 | 2022-06-01 | 300 | 0 | 0 | -300 | 0 |

I see this occurring in four steps:

1. Partitioning by `account_id` and ordering by `sale_month`
2. Inserting missing dates within these groups as new records into the table
3. Calculating `revenue_closing`
4. Calculating `revenue_opening` using a window function

It is step 1 and 2 that have me stumped. I am not sure how to write an insert statement that operates within an ordered partition and knows to only insert records for dates that do not exist.

I suppose I could always create a `dim_dates` table and left join `revenue_table` to that, but that approach strikes me as being clunky.

Any / all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I agree that creating dim_dates and using window functions is the right approach to solve this. However, it can be solved using recursive CTE as well.

I am adding my version of SQL that uses recursive CTE.

```
with sales_data (account_id, sale_month, revenue_new, revenue_expansion, revenue_churn) as /* sample date */
(
    select * from
    (
    values ('000001', '2022-01-01', 100, 0, 0)
            , ('000001', '2022-03-01', 0, 200, 0)
            , ('000001', '2022-06-01', 0, 0, -300)
            -- added two more records for validation
            , ('000002', '2022-01-01', 100, 0, 0)
            , ('000002', '2022-04-01', 0, 400, 0)
            , ('000002', '2022-07-01', 0, 0, -500)
    )
), sales_month_range as /* getting date range for each account_id */
(
    select account_id
            , min(sale_month::date) as begin_date
            , max(sale_month::date) as end_date
    from sales_data
    group by account_id
), rec_sales_month as /* recursive cte to fill missing dates and calculate opening and closing balance */
(
    select sd.account_id
            , sd.sale_month::date as sale_month
            , 0 as revenue_opening
            , sd.revenue_new 
            , sd.revenue_expansion
            , sd.revenue_churn
            , (nvl(sd.revenue_new, 0) 
                + nvl(sd.revenue_expansion, 0)) 
                + nvl(sd.revenue_churn, 0
              ) as revenue_closing
            , r.end_date as end_date
    from sales_month_range r
    inner join sales_data sd
        on sd.account_id = r.account_id
            and sd.sale_month::date = r.begin_date::date
    where r.begin_date::date <= r.end_date::date
    union all
    select r.account_id
            , dateadd(month, 1, r.sale_month::date) as sale_month
            , r.revenue_closing as revenue_opening
            , nvl(sd.revenue_new, 0) as revenue_new
            , nvl(sd.revenue_expansion, 0) as revenue_expansion
            , nvl(sd.revenue_churn, 0) as revenue_churn
            , (
                nvl(r.revenue_closing, 0) 
                + nvl(sd.revenue_new, 0) 
                + nvl(sd.revenue_expansion, 0)
                + nvl(sd.revenue_churn, 0)
              ) as revenue_closing
            , r.end_date
    from rec_sales_month r
    left join sales_data sd
        on sd.account_id = r.account_id
            and dateadd(month, 1, r.sale_month::date) = sd.sale_month
    where dateadd(month, 1, r.sale_month::date) <= r.end_date::date
)
select account_id
        , sale_month
        , revenue_opening
        , revenue_new
        , revenue_expansion
        , revenue_churn
        , revenue_closing
from rec_sales_month
--where account_id = '000001'
order by account_id, sale_month::date
```

**sales_data**

- This CTE contains sample data
- I have added few more records for another account_id **000002** to validate the solution

**sales_month_range**

- This CTE will give me the date range for each account. So that I can use it to fill the missing dates

**rec_sales_month**

- This is recursive CTE and it contains the main logic to fill the missing dates and calculate the opening/closing balance.

Snowflake documentation is available here that you can refer to understand the recursive CTE.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/queries-cte.html#recursive-ctes-and-hierarchical-data

Hope this will help!